# Issue - Using CEFSharp WinForm will return blank page when use Proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I using CEFSharp WinForm to call website, but return the result must be a blank page when using a Proxy server. If I turn off the proxy server setting, the website would be displayed.

And I use `chrome://net-internals/#proxy`, is confirm the proxy setting already updated. And the proxy server is valid because I can use PC chrome to connect the proxy server and display the website.

Below is my background:

Window 10, VS version is 2015, CEFSharp uses NuGet to install the version is 75.1.141.

And using this link the example to change the script to use a proxy server
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

In the CEFSharp WinForm the Program.cs - Main function, below is my script:

```
public static void Main() {

        Cef.EnableHighDPISupport();

        var settings = new CefSettings()
        {
            CachePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "CefSharp\\Cache")
        };

        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "1");

        //This is my set proxy-server the script, and I tried two ways, but the result same as blank page.
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", "123.1.170.138:3128");
        //CefSharp.CefSharpSettings.Proxy = new CefSharp.ProxyOptions("123.1.170.138", "3128");

        Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);

        var browser = new BrowserForm();
        Application.Run(browser);
    }
```

My expected the result is out the webpage use proxy server.
But actual result is blank page.

In debug.log file only have below the log

> [0907/095945.451:ERROR:browser_process_sub_thread.cc(221)] Waited 157 ms for network service

Comment: Download the `CEF Sample Application` from http://opensource.spotify.com/cefbuilds/cef_binary_75.1.14%2Bgc81164e%2Bchromium-75.0.3770.100_windows32_client.tar.bz2 use the command line args listed at https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/GeneralUsage.md#markdown-header-proxy-resolution confirm that the proxy is actually working on CEF. If the proxy requires authentication then you'll need to handle that in code.

Comment: Noted, I will try it, and post the result in this post.

Comment: Hi @amaitland, I used below the command to call the CEF Sample Application (cefclient.exe --proxy-server=123.1.170.138:3128), below is the result.

Page failed to load.
URL: http://www.google.com/
Error: UNKNOWN (-130)
ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED

Comment: For whatever reason `CEF` doesn't like your proxy. Can you try a different proxy?

Comment: I need found other proxy, can you confirm my running the method is right? and the CEF version is no bug for proxy issue.

Comment: You can ask on https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php

Comment: `Proxy settings are configured in CEF3 using the same command-line flags as Google Chrome.` I should point of that if the command line arg works in `Chrome` then it's probably correct.

Comment: CEF3 using the same command-line flags to add the proxy server, when I tried more times, maybe have one time have the result (have not occur proxy connect error), but is not stable. I cannot sure this is the proxy issue or CEF issue. But I use PC chrome have not this problem. This maybe Chrome and CEF the different.

Comment: Then I use same the proxy server and tried more times in CEFSharp WInForm, return the result as same on CEF, maybe have one time can return the result, is not a blank page. I not sure this is the proxy server issue or CEF unstable problem. But the result is less than Chrome.